# Parse Date "2015-02-23T10:47:00+10:00"

Tags: java, date, format

I have the following `DateFormat` in Java:

```
DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM Z'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

When I try to parse the following date I get an `'Unparseable date' exception: "2015-02-23T10:47:00+10:00"`.

What `DateFormat` should I use instead?

Comment: It looks like you're missing dd

Comment: The format is called ISO 8601 - possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat DATE_FORMAT =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
```